# Xcode 7.3 SDK iOS 9.3, XCTest UI unit tests failing

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, xctest

I have been using `XCTest` UI unit tests in my app, it worked great with Xcode 7.2. with base SDK iOS 9.2, but as soon as I tried to run them with Xcode 7.3, with bas SDK iOS 9.3, all of them are failing.

After looking at the issue, it seems that after the app launches, it tries to tap on the buttons a little too fast, note that at this point I can assert for the existence of the button with a simple `NSPredicate`, and it does in fact exist, the engine finds it, but when it tries the tap, despite not failing in the logs, the method for the `IBAction` does NOT get called.

I created a brand new project to test this issue, first I simply created a single view application, no navigation controller involved, with a single `UIButton`, and hooked up the IBAction to the view controller, then simply added this UI unit test:

```
    func testExample()
{
    XCUIApplication().buttons["Button"].tap()
}
```

And set a breakpoint in the `IBAction` method on my view controller, it got called. Then I decided to make my `UIViewController` with the button the root view controller of a `UINavigationController`, ran the same test, and now the tap does not work!. If I add a simple delay such as:

```
    func testExample()
{
    sleep(1)
    XCUIApplication().buttons["Button"].tap()
}
```

Then the button tap happens, and the executions stops on the IBAction breakpoint, If I run this code without the sleep in Xcode 7.2. it also gets called. There seems to be a definite problem with Xcode 7.3 or rather iOS Base SDK 9.3, with `XCTest` UI testing, I know i can simply add `sleep` at `setUp` for all test cases, and they work, however this is a big hack, surprisingly I could not find any topics online with this issue, anyone else experiencing the same and has a good work around for it?

It seems to work as long as you wait more than 0.3 seconds, that is

```
NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval(0.4) // works
NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval(0.3) // Does not work
```

Curiously enough the animation for a view controller push is 0.35 seconds, note that I am not pushing anything, but simply adding the view controller as the root view controller, but just found that apparent relation interesting.

Comment: Maybe it is because the animation going on from the `LaunchScreen.xib` to the `rootViewController`?

Comment: @NSGangster that could be the cause, but I would expect it to behave the same way regardless of it being inside a navigation controller or not.

Comment: Installing the iOS 9.2 simulator again seems to be a workaround, instead of sleep. But ideally want to get this working with iOS 9.3 simulators.